# How to send the log in the body of an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this code I put together, but I didn't know how to send the log in the body of the email. So instead, I just put console.log. This is all that I did:

```
 function myFunction() {

 console.log('log1')
 console.log('log2')
 console.log('log3')


var recipent = 'ar07832@students.leeschools.net';
var heading = 'Heading';
var body = console.log;
MailApp.sendEmail(recipent, heading, body);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function myFunction() {
   Logger.log('log1')
   Logger.log('log2')
   Logger.log('log3')
   var recipent = "your email";
   var heading = 'Heading';
   var body = Logger.getLog();
   MailApp.sendEmail(recipent, heading, body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include that I already tried Logger.getLog();. But whatever else you did, it worked

Comment: I just used Logger for all four statements

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind the `console.log` function and change its behavior. Then, you can read your saved logs to send it somewhere else.

Please note that using an array is just a suggestion, not a rule.

```
// Bind the original function.
console.normalLog = console.log.bind(console);

// Create an empty array of logs.
console.savedLogs = [];

// Create the new logging function.
console.log = function(){
    // Save each log in the array.
    console.savedLogs.push(Array.from(arguments));

    // Execute the normal logging function.
    console.normalLog.apply(console, arguments);
}

// Logging...
console.log('test 1');
console.log('test 2');

// Checking the saved logs.
console.normalLog(console.savedLogs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to save the logs, instead of console.log() or Logger.log():

```
function myFunction() {
// Create an array
  arr = [];
  arr.push('log1');
  arr.push('log2');
  arr.push('log3')

var recipent = 'ar07832@students.leeschools.net';
var heading = 'Heading';
var body = arr;
MailApp.sendEmail(recipent, heading, body);
}
```